# CentOS limits.conf & cpulimit not working

Tags: centos, webserver, limit

I have a CentOS server I am testing things out on.

In it, I have configured

```
USERNAME    hard    maxlogins    4
USERNAME    hard    cpu    1
USERNAME    hard    nproc    10
```

in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

and

```
USERNAME    hard    maxlogins    4
USERNAME    hard    cpu    1
USERNAME    hard    nproc    10
```

in `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`

Have also set a `/etc/init.d script` with the following

```
cpulimit -l 10 /usr/sbin/mysqld & 
cpulimit -l 10 /usr/bin/php &
```

yet, when I run

```
ab -n 2000 -c 100 http://USERNAME.com/
```

and watch `top -c` I can see that they all get ignored, and end up with 150+ `USERNAME`, mysqld spikes out around 30%, and php for each `USERNAME` hits about 2-3% each

How can I set this up properly to limit maxlogins, cpu, nproc for `USERNAME`, and how is it that mysqld is still punching past that 10% mark?

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Comment: CentOS 6.5 + 6.6